# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2: Failed to apply plugin, when using gradle 3.0.0-alpha2

Tags: java, android, gradle, aspectj, android-studio-3.0

I just updated to using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2. Upon opening my project Android Studio suggested I update the gradle version to 3.0.0-alpha2. My goal is to use the "Enable advanced profiling" Run Configuration so I can run a realtime memory-analysis. However the instant my gradle version was updated, my project fails to build. I followed the update instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html).

The only changes made were to my top-level build.gradle file and the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

My top-level **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath 'com.github.Archinamon:GradleAspectJ-Android:2.3.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/' }
        maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
    }
}
```

And I updated the **gradle-wrapper.properties** distributionURL to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

The error I get is:

> Failed to apply plugin [id'com.archinamon.aspectJ']

And here is the offending part of my **app-level build.gradle** file:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.archinamon.aspectj'
aspectj {
    includeAspectsFromJar 'Android_MTAgent'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
....
}
```

So the problem seems to be with the aspectJ plugin. If I remove the plugin for aspectJ and the related aspectJ block (both shown above) then it compiles (I get a dimen error then though, but I already saw that mentioned elsewhere, so I guess that can be solved.)

I'd appreciate any pointers/ideas in regard to the above issue.

Comment: This question is also answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364630/unable-to-run-project-after-update-to-android-studio-preview-3-0-canary-3

Comment: @sgupta Looks like the question you linked is a duplicate and it doesn't talk at all about the really relevant part of this question: The AspectJ plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

and update your Archinamon classpath reference in the same build.gradle file to:

```
classpath 'com.github.Archinamon:GradleAspectJ-Android:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately this does not fix the original error, however it adds another error: compleSdkVersion is not specified, which is not true, as I have it set: compileSdkVersion 25

Comment: Try classpath 'com.github.Archinamon:GradleAspectJ-Android:3.0.2'

Comment: Ah good catch! This actually works! Now I'll just have to fix all the other errors that the Canary Release brings with it :)