# Unable to Build Project after update to android studio preview 3.0 canary 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I Just update my android studio preview 3.0 canary 3. After this I am trying to run the project but showing following error.

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/opt/android-studio-preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
    file:/opt/android-studio-preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: You should read here to be sure that you have migrated to the new plugin correctly: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html

Comment: I rolled back the question to the original question, you should not change the question after asking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main things you need to do are:

Change your project level `build.gradle` file to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}
```

Change the `distributionUrl` of your gradle-wrapper.properties to the currently latest available release of Gradle.

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-rc-1-all.zip
```

After this steps your project could not compile yet, and you need to follow all the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_aware) on how to convert your app `build.gradle` to the new plugin

Answer (score 0):

Change your `build.gradle (project_name)` 's one line(`classpath`) as per update:-

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```